# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlesearch'

Tags: python, google-api

```
from googlesearch import search


query = "see"

links = []
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
    links.append(j)
print(links)
```

I've done absolutely everything I can in my power to make it work. I did all of the things mentioned below:

1. pip install google
2. pip install google-search
3. pip install google-cloud

Comment: I ran the program and it worked for me. All I had to do was `pip install google`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you do this?

```
pip install googlesearch-python
```

Because that is the command you have to run to install googlesearch.

Comment: Be careful!!!!!!!!! I saw this answer and just pip installed it. I shouldn't obviously. Read the entire answer

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with Conda, I used venv and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reading better pypi.org, I precised still my installation like this, :
python3 -m pip install googlesearch-python
this in a venv like I use to...